# PPT does not show all the slides when I do the slide show

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am having a strange issue. When I play a slide show I can not see all the slides. But when I  open the slides in my MS powerpoint for edit, I see all the slides. Any reason for that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

The slides you don't see might be hidden.  In the thumbnails pane, look for a slash through the slide number at the upper left of the slide thumbnail.  In slide sorter view, hidden slides have a slash through the number at the lower right of the slide thumbnail image.

In either case, right click the slide thumbnail and click Hide Slide again to toggle the hidden-ness off.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a Custom Presentation set by error:

Open the presentation.
On the Slide Show menu, click Set Up Show.
In Show Slide set ALL (not Curstom presentation)
Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Slide Show menu, click Set Up Show. In Show Slide select ALL and Click OK. Please see the screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot]